# PHP Add to Multidimensional Array using mysql_fetch

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I've looked on the web but all I can find is how to echo data from arrays, but I need to add to them. This array is multidimensional so I need to add an array to an array all the time. How do I do this?

Heres the code:

```
<?php 
$data = array(
    "contacts" => array(
        array(
            'id'=> "1",
            'catagory'=> "LifeStyle",
            'title'=> "Some Cool Title",
            'url'=> "http://example.com",
        ),
    )
);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM magazines WHERE category = '$cat'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row["id"]; 
    $cat = $row["category"];
    $title = $row["title"];  
    $url = $row["url"];

    // add to array 
//  array(
//      'id'=> "$id",
//      'catagory'=> "$cat",
//      'title'=> "$title",
//      'url'=> "$url",
//  ),  
}
mysql_close();
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: `$data['contacts'][] = $row` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

 $data['contacts'][] = $row;
}
```

Or this...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 array_push($data['contacts'], $row);
}
```

Then a print_r will show you your array...

```
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `SELECT *` select only the fields you want to push into the array. Something like this

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, category, title, url FROM magazines WHERE category = '$cat'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $data['contacts'][] = $row;
    }
?>
```